# In excel under a single cell I want to have a table format with borders. I want to achieve this without merging

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I got a requirement wherein a single cell without merging with other cells I want a table format with borders. I had the data as follows in the cell

[image]

I don't want to merge any other cells, but just wanted to add the table with formatted borders with the mentioned data. The data should like below.

[image]

It would be really appreciated if someone can help me in achieving this. I am looking out for a solution where in I would like to have it in text format only not in the image

Comment: Just type it in, like you have there?  You haven't said anything about any data sources, et cetera…

Comment: I need to have the format as table with lines

Comment: Format the borders. Then copy as a picture. Then paste the picture into an enlarged cell.  Set properties to move and size with the cell.

Comment: @BharadwajaBapatla Thank you for clarifying, and for editing in the second picture to illustrate the desired result ☺

Comment: @RonRosenfeld really thanks for your comment, I am aware of this method but unlikely it won't work in my scenario as I need to send the document into a shared folder and people tend to edit the details. I am looking out for a solution where in I would like to have it in text format only not in the image

Comment: I will follow this question, but I do not think it possible to have an editable formatted table within a single Excel cell.  Probably you will need to think of a different solution. Consider picture with a hyperlink to a data entry form?  Using just a data entry form for your users to edit? And there are probably other solutions also.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to include an entire formatted table in a single cell is to copy the table and pasteAsPicture.  Then by adjusting column widths and row heights, put the picture in a single cell.  Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

No merged cells are used.  The picture of the table is in cell **D8**.

Comment: Hi really thanks for your answer, I am aware of this method but unlikely it won't work in my scenario as I need to send the document into a shared folder and people tend to edit the details. I am looking out for a solution where in I would like to have it in text format only not in the image

Comment: @BharadwajaBapatla  If this approach is of no value to you, I will delete the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would slightly increase the width and double the height of the cell, but Unicode includes the following characters for creating a text table:

```
┌┬┐─
├┼┤│
└┴┘
╔╦╗═
╠╬╣║
╚╩╝
```